# Express: PayloadTooLargeError trying to read POST body containing large JSON despite limits set

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following main app.js and a supporting file containing some routing handlers

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var testRouter = require('./routes/test');
var routineRouter = require('./routes/routines');

var app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/test', testRouter);
app.use('/routine', routineRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

/routes/routines.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var path = require('path');

router.post('/changeBoundary', function(req, res, next) {
    let id = req.body.precinctId;
    let geo = req.body.polygon;
    res.status = 200;
    res.end();
});
```

I am trying to pass a fairly large JSON file (probably around 5-10mb?) into that 'changeBoundary' handler but I am getting the 'too large' error. I've set the size limits on the body-parser to be larger than I should be needing and I've made sure everything is in the right order but I'm still getting the error. This is my first time using Node.js at all so I'm still trying to figure out how all the different parts fit together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching it from

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
```

to

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

solved the issue. I don't really know exactly why other than that the order things are loaded matters.

Comment: 2x express.urlencoded() is probably conflicting, they internally are doing the same thing